# Trying to use WireUI x-select to display dynamic options

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to render the options of the select component dynamically and it renders fine, the problem is that id doesn't send the data back to the component it fails the validations and it just not sent back

this is the component

```
    use Actions;

    public $model;
    public $modelName;
    public $modelClass;
    public $modelInstance;
    public $fields;
    public $count;

    protected $validationAttributes = [];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->modelName =  ucfirst($this->model);
        $this->model = [];
        $this->modelClass = '\App\Models\' . $this->modelName;
        $this->modelInstance = new $this->modelClass;
        $this->fields = $this->modelInstance->getFields();
        $this->count = count($this->fields);
        // Initialize the model array with null values for each field
        foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
            $this->model[$field] = null;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-model', [
            'getFieldOptions' => function ($field) {
                return $this->getFieldOptions($field);
            },
        ]);
    }

    public static function modalMaxWidth(): string
    {
        return '2xl';
    }

    protected function rules()
    {
        $this->validationAttributes = $this->modelInstance->getValidationAttributes();
        return $this->modelInstance->getRules();
    }

    protected function getFieldOptions($field)
    {
        $relatedModel = str_replace('_id', '', $field);
        $relatedModel = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $relatedModel)));
        $relatedClass = '\App\Models\' . $relatedModel;

        return $relatedClass::all();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
        $model = $this->modelClass::create($validatedData['model']);

        $this->closeModalWithEvents([
            $this->emit('pg:eventRefresh-default')
        ]);
        $this->notification([
            'title' => $model->name . ' created!',
            'icon' => 'success',
            'iconColor' => 'text-positive-600'
        ]);
    }
```

this is the view I'm using wire elements modal btw

```
<div>
    <x-wire-modal formAction="create">
        <x-slot name="title">
            {{ __('Create ' . $modelName) }}
        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="content">
            <div
                class="
                grid gap-4 
                @if ($count > 10) md:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-1
                @elseif ($count > 1 && $count < 10)
                grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2
                @elseif ($count = 1)
                md:grid-cols-1 grid-cols-1 @endif">
                @foreach ($fields as $field => $icon)
                    @if (strpos($field, '_id') !== false)
                        <div>
                            <x-select label="{{ ucfirst(str_replace('_id', '', $field)) }}"
                                wire:model.defer="model.{{ $field }}" wire:key="model.{{ $field . now() }}">
                                @foreach ($getFieldOptions($field) as $option)
                                    <x-select.option label="{{ $option->name }}" value="{{ $option->id }}" />
                                @endforeach
                            </x-select>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <div>
                            <x-input label="{{ ucfirst($field) }}" wire:model.defer="model.{{ $field }}" />
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>

        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="buttons">
            <x-button wire:click="$emit('closeModal')" negative label="{{ __('Nevermind') }}" />
            <x-button type="submit" primary label="{{ __('Create') }}" />
        </x-slot>
    </x-wire-modal>
</div>
```

this is the modal where the fields and rules are set

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'type',
        'control_effectiveness',
        'inherent_risk_assessment',
        'residual_risk_assessment',
        'status',
        'project_id',
        'company_id',
        'department_id',
        'risk_function_id',
        'objective_id',
        'risk_source_id',
        'category_id',
        'asset_id',
        'standard_clause_id',
        'likelihood_id',
        'impact_id',
        'threat_id',
        'threat_level_equation_id',
        'treatment_strategy_id',
        'control_id',
        'employee_id',
    ];

    public function getRules()
    {
        $rules = [];
        foreach ($this->fillable as $field) {
            $rules["model.$field"] = '';
        }
        return $rules;
    }

    public function getValidationAttributes()
    {
        $validationAttributes = [];
        foreach ($this->fillable as $field) {
            $validationAttributes["model.$field"] = ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $field));
        }
        return $validationAttributes;
    }

    public function getFields()
    {
        $fields = [];
        foreach ($this->fillable as $field) {
            $fields[$field] = '';
        }
        return $fields;
    }
```

Help is much appreciated

after a lot of search I found that the problem is somehow related to [`@entagle`](https://laracasts.com/@entagle) I went on WireUi github page and found these 3 related issues [`https://github.com/wireui/wireui/issues/513`](https://github.com/wireui/wireui/issues/513) [`https://github.com/wireui/wireui/issues/618`](https://github.com/wireui/wireui/issues/618) [`https://github.com/wireui/wireui/issues/339`](https://github.com/wireui/wireui/issues/339) however I tried the fixes mentioned there but with no luck